# AES - MixColumn transformation using the identity matrix

Tags: aes, block-cipher

I'm analysing how different components of AES influence its security. However, I cannot find a good explanation to what happens if the MixColumn step would use the identity matrix. Intuition tells me, that then AES won't be secure, but why?

Comment: mixcolumns mixes the column diffusively through matrix multiplication, if you use the identity matrix, that is equivalent to not applying any multiplication, so it would not... mix

Comment: [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) and look at ShiftRows and MixColumn. This will help you to see poncho's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you eliminate the MixColumn (or equivalently, replace it with an identity Matrix), then the resulting cipher will effectively be 4 independent 32 bit block ciphers.  This happens because what happens in one 32 bit row no longer has any propagation to any of the other 3 32 bit rows.

This results in a much weaker cipher; not only would that bring up possible chosen plaintext/ciphertext attacks (where you modify one of the 32 bit blocks, but leave the other 3 the same), you would also have ciphertext only attacks with a birthday bound of circa 256k...

Comment: I would like to add that; ShiftRows and MixXomun are together the permutations of the AES to form the SPN network.

Comment: wouldnt it be 16 independent 8-bit block ciphers? related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34928/what-would-happen-to-aes-if-we-replaced-mixcolumns-with-shiftcolumns/34951#34951

Comment: @RichieFrame: hmmmm, good point; I had initially thought that the ShiftRows would do the intra-row propagation; obviously, it doesn't actually do that...

Answer (score 0):

The identity matrix has a branch number of 2 which means there is no mixing. one active cell in the input column will produce  the same active cell in the output column.